# Show with the help of binomial theorem that these two equations are equal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Show with the help of binomial theorem that these two expression are equal for $n\ge 0$ then this $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k x^k (2+x)^k = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom {2n} k x^k $$

I don’t know how to do it but here is the answer.

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k x^k (2+x)^k &=  
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k (2x+x^2)^k \\ &= [\text{binomi} \\ &= (1+2x+x^2)^n \\ &= (1+x)^{2n} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom {2n} k x^k. \end{align}

I don’t understand why they were able to multiply $x^k(2+x)^k$ and then get $(1+2x+x^2)$. How did binomial theorem make it possible?

Comment: Apply binomial theorem : 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k = (1 + a)^n$$
for $a = 2 x + x^2$.

Answer (score 3):

First step is just $a^n b^n = (ab)^n$.

Second step is:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k (2x+x^2)^k &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k \color{blue}{\boldsymbol{1^{n-k}}} (2x+x^2)^k \\ &= \text{Binomial expansion} \\ &\qquad\qquad \text{of $1$ and $2x+x^2$} \\ &= \big(1+2x+x^2\big)^n \\ &= \big((1+x)^2\big)^n \\ &= (1+x)^{2n}.
\end{align}
Then apply the binomial theorem.

Comment: Just one question: where did you get 1^(n-k) from, did you just add it from nowhere because no matter what random number y that 1^y, it will always be one?

Comment: **Yes, that’s why.**